# Or statement in C++ template programming

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, specialization

I have a program structured roughly like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Output
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    Output& operator&(T const& t)
    {
        std::cout << t << std::endl;

        return *this;
    }
};

class Input
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    Input& operator&(T& t)
    {
        std::cin >> t;

        return *this;
    }
};

class C
{
    public:
        int num1, num2;
};

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, Input>::value>::type operator&(T& t, C& c)
{
    t & c.num1 & c.num2;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, Output>::value>::type operator&(T& t, C& c)
{
    t & c.num1 & c.num2;
}

int main()
{
    Output o;
    Input i;
    C c;

    i & c;
    o & c;

    return 0;
}
```

It works great but I would ideally like to combine the functions `typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, Input>::value>::type operator&(T& t, C& c)` and `typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, Output>::value>::type operator&(T& t, C& c)`. So I am looking for something like `typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, Input>::value || std::is_same<T, Output>::value>>::type operator&(T& t, C& c)`. Do C++ templates provide such 'or' statement?

Comment: You've answered your own question---you can use `||` exactly as you would like to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is really simple - use `||` - exactly what you have in your question. The first argument to `enable_if` is a `bool`, so you can use any combination of expressions that yield a compile-time boolean value.

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<T, Input>::value ||
    std::is_same<T, Output>::value
>::type operator&(T& t, C& c)
{
    t & c.num1 & c.num2;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdf5e81209cbb29a)

Comment: Umm, oops. I thought I tried that. I may have typed something wrong. Thanks.